# MATLAB:To create segments of numeric values continously ordered

Tags: matlab, sorting, vector

A simple MATLAB-problem:

```
coordinates=[1 6 ;9 20];

coordinates =

     1     6
     9    20
```

What i now want to have is:

```
   idxList=[1 2 3 4 5 6 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20];


idxList =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     9    10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20
```

How i have to make that?

Comment: `[coordinates(1, 1):coordinates(1, 2) coordinates(2, 1):coordinates(2, 2)]`

Comment: what about coordinates with 7 or 14 rows? should i do that in a loop?

Comment: `cell2mat(arrayfun(@(i)coordinates(i, 1):coordinates(i, 2), size(coordinates, 1), 'uniformoutput', 0))` will work, though I think there must be an easier way. Depending on what kind of numbers you get in `coordinates` you might also want to do `sort` and `unique` on the output of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
>> cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) x(1):x(2), num2cell(coordinates, 2), 'UniformOutput', 0)')

ans =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     9    10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20
```